# Write a query to get last seven month records from a table

Tags: sql-server-2008

Im having two tables TableA and TableB.

TableA is a master table.

**TableA:**

```
+-------+---------+
|   Id  |   Asset |
+-------+---------+
|   1   |  Asset1 |
|   2   |  Asset2 |
|   3   |  Asset3 |
|   4   |  Asset4 |
|   5   |  Asset5 |
+-------+---------+
```

**TableB:**

```
+-------+---------+-------------+
|   Id  |   Asset |   ScanDate  |
+-------+---------+-------------+
|   1   |  Asset1 | 12/Jun/2014 |
|   2   |  Asset2 | 12/Jun/2014 |
|   3   |  Asset3 | 12/Jun/2014 |
|   4   |  Asset4 | 12/Jun/2014 |
|   5   |  Asset5 | 12/Jun/2014 |
|   6   |  Asset1 | 13/Jun/2014 |
|   7   |  Asset2 | 13/Jun/2014 |
|   8   |  Asset3 | 13/Jun/2014 |
|   9   |  Asset4 | 13/Jun/2014 |
|  10   |  Asset5 | 13/Jun/2014 |
|  11   |  Asset1 | 14/Jun/2014 |
|  12   |  Asset2 | 14/Jun/2014 |
|  13   |  Asset3 | 14/Jun/2014 |
|  14   |  Asset4 | 14/Jun/2014 |
|  15   |  Asset5 | 14/Jun/2014 |
|  16   |  Asset1 | 15/Jun/2014 |
|  17   |  Asset2 | 15/Jun/2014 |
|  18   |  Asset5 | 15/Jun/2014 |
|  19   |  Asset1 | 16/Jun/2014 |
|  20   |  Asset2 | 16/Jun/2014 |
|  21   |  Asset3 | 16/Jun/2014 |
|  22   |  Asset1 | 18/Jun/2014 |
|  23   |  Asset2 | 18/Jun/2014 |
|  24   |  Asset3 | 18/Jun/2014 |
|  25   |  Asset4 | 18/Jun/2014 |
|  26   |  Asset5 | 18/Jun/2014 |
|  27   |  Asset3 | 19/Jun/2014 |
|  28   |  Asset4 | 19/Jun/2014 |
|  29   |  Asset5 | 19/Jun/2014 |
|  30   |  Asset4 | 20/Jun/2014 |
|  31   |  Asset5 | 20/Jun/2014 |
+-------+---------+-------------+
```

I need to check the assets scanned on last seven days.

I need my output as below:

```
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Asset  |13/Jun/2014|14/Jun/2014|15/Jun/2014|16/Jun/2014|17/Jun/2014|18/Jun/2014|19/Jun/2014|20/Jun/2014|
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Asset1 |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |  Yes      |  No       |  No       |
| Asset2 |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |  Yes      |  No       |  No       |
| Asset3 |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |  Yes      |  No       |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |
| Asset4 |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |  No       |  No       |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |
| Asset5 |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |  No       |  No       |  Yes      |  Yes      |  Yes      |
+--------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

How to write a query to get the above output.
Please help me out.

I tried the below query:

```
DECLARE @Now DATETIME = GETDATE();
DECLARE @7DaysAgo DATETIME = DATEADD(day,-10,@Now);

SELECT LastScanDate 
FROM   TableB
WHERE  ScanDate BETWEEN @7DaysAgo AND @Now 
group  BY ScanDate
```

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar : i have tried the above mentioned query.

Comment: @Deepak You want last 7 months data or last 7 days? In your title you have mentioned Months and in your query it's Days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I came up with M Khalid Junaid Idea

Try this

```
Select T1.Asset,
Sum(Case When Cast(GETDATE() As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) current_day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -1, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -2, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) Second_last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -3, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) Third_last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -4, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) fourth_last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -5, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) fifth_last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -6, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) sixth_last_Day,
Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) Seventh_last_Day
From Table1 T1 Left Join Table2 T2 On(T1.Asset = T2.Asset)
Group By T1.Asset;
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1086f/16)**

**OutPut:**

```
ASSET   CURRENT_DAY LAST_DAY    SECOND_LAST_DAY THIRD_LAST_DAY  FOURTH_LAST_DAY FIFTH_LAST_DAY  SIXTH_LAST_DAY  SEVENTH_LAST_DAY
Asset1  0           0           1           0                   1               1               1               1
Asset2  0           0           1           0                   1               1               1               1
Asset3  0           1           1           0                   1               0               1               1
Asset4  1           1           1           0                   0               0               1               1
Asset5  1           1           1           0                   0               1               1               1
```

---

**Update**

If you want Column Value With `Yes` or `No`

Try This

```
Select T1.Asset,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(GETDATE() As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End Today,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -1, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End Last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -2, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End Second_last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -3, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End Third_last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -4, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End fourth_last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -5, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End fifth_last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -6, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End sixth_last_Day,
Case When Sum(Case When Cast(DATEADD(Day, -7, GETDATE()) As Date) = Cast(T1.ScanDate AS Date) Then 1 else 0 end) = 1 Then 'Yes' else 'No' End Seventh_last_Day
From Table1 T1 Left Join Table2 T2 On(T1.Asset = T2.Asset)
Group By T1.Asset;
```

**[Live Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1086f/23)**

**Output:**

```
ASSET   TODAY   LAST_DAY    SECOND_LAST_DAY THIRD_LAST_DAY  FOURTH_LAST_DAY FIFTH_LAST_DAY  SIXTH_LAST_DAY  SEVENTH_LAST_DAY
Asset1  No      No          Yes             No              Yes             Yes             Yes             Yes
Asset2  No      No          Yes             No              Yes             Yes             Yes             Yes
Asset3  No      Yes         Yes             No              Yes             No              Yes             Yes
Asset4  Yes     Yes         Yes             No              No              No              Yes             Yes
Asset5  Yes     Yes         Yes             No              No              Yes             Yes             Yes
```